# Comparing logistic regression models from two data sets when a parameter isn't varied in one data set but is in the other

Tags: hypothesis-testing, logistic, model-comparison, out-of-sample

I want to determine if a logistic regression model makes good predictions for a data set not used in its fitting with a hypothesis test; I'll call it the "new" data. One could say that the null hypothesis is that there is one model describing both data sets; the alternative says this is false.

I could easily imagine a likelihood test or an asymptotic test that directly compares coefficients in regression models fit to the two data sets directly, but unfortunately I would not be able to fit the model to the new data since there is a dummy variable in the new data that isn't varied, while it is varied in the old data. Hence I would not be able to estimate the same model for both data sets; that dummy would need to be dropped in the model fit to the new data.

One strategy would be to see if, by adding a dummy variable tracking whether the data is from the "old" or "new" data, that dummy variable is not zero; that would at least be sensitive to a "rigid shift" in the model, or a difference in the intercept term of the models. But it may not be sensitive to other differences.

Is there another way to deal with the fact that a dummy variable isn't varied in the new data?

I do not want to discuss my data directly. I'm willing to imagine, as an example, working with the `iris` data set and trying to predict whether the sepal length exceeds 1 (just to make it binary) using sepal width, petal length, petal width, and species as regressors. One data set has examples of all species of flower, but the other data set only has setosa flowers.

Comment: Could you please post an example of your data? I am confused about this idea of a dummy variable not varying.

Comment: @Dave I would if I could. Let's imagine it's like the iris data, but in the new data set, there's only setosa flowers, while in the original data set all species are represented. Is that helpful?

Comment: Then what do you have to model in the data set with just setosa?

Comment: @Dave Well, while you only see setosa flowers, the other variables still exist and still vary. So let's just say we're trying to predict whether sepal length is above 1 (to make it binary), and we have access to sepal width, petal length, petal width, and species. In the new data, you only see setosa, but everything else still sees variation.

Comment: Please do not give new information only in comments, edit 
 your question to add the new information. We want posts to 
 be self-contained, comments can be deleted, and anyhow, 
 information in comments are not well organized. Also, many 
 people do not read comments.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Done.